# Claims-Aware WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

what is mean by "Claims-Aware WCF Service"

Is it a standard?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545447(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

A couple of clicks away from the [page you linked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545447(v=vs.110).aspx): [Getting Started With WIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545426(v=vs.110).aspx) > [Windows Identity Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377151(v=vs.110).aspx) > [Claims-Based Identity Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873308(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When you build claims-aware applications, the user identity is represented in your application as a set of claims. One claim could be the user’s name, another might be an e-mail address. The idea is that an external identity system is configured to give your application everything it needs to know about the user with each request she makes, along with cryptographic assurance that the identity data you receive comes from a trusted source.
>
> Under this model, single sign-on is much easier to achieve, and your application is no longer responsible for the following:
>
> - Authenticating users.
> - Storing user accounts and passwords.
> - Calling to enterprise directories to look up user identity details.
> - Integrating with identity systems from other platforms or companies.
>
> Under this model, your application makes identity-related decisions based on claims supplied by the system that authenticated your user. This could be anything from simple application personalization wit

Comment: Well done and IMHO that's one too many clicks away than it should be. Now I've got some more light reading to do. :)